# How to check number of fields filled out?

Tags: javascript, html, logic

i am stuck in this small issue:

i have a page where user can fill out up to 10 fields. but he doesnot have to, he can also fill out only one. at first, user has only one field, then he can add more fields with `add` button.

my problem is: how can i know how many fields the user has added and filled out, so that i can save them into db?

my vision is this:

i will count the fields and then i pass this sum to serverside code. then there, i will loop sum-times and ....? i am stuck here, :(

can someone suggest me pls simpler logic,

thanks a lot

Comment: some code can be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can utilize the array-functionality of HTML-Elements.

Have all fields have a `name` like this:

```
<input type="text" name="Set[]"></input>
```

In this case, your `$_POST`-array will have an array called `Set`, which you can just iterate through. Discard those, where `empty()` returns `true` and you're all set.

Edit: Replaced fixed indices with automatic increment.

Comment: Actually `name="Set[]"` would be better.

Comment: At least you don't have to have Javascript involved. And you can always `count()` the array PHP side.

Comment: @Jeffrey Most definitely, yes. I edited my answer accordingly. Thank you for the input.

Answer (score 1):

A better idea to do this could be:

When you click on add button to add another textfield, a save button is displayed along with it and save the value instantly using jquery ajax.

Answer (score 1):

```
var numberoffields = 0;
addfield(){
//your code to add field here
numberoffields += 1;
}
```

and post 'numberoffields' to your server

Comment: thanks, nice, but how do i catch the values then in server depending on this sum?

Comment: based on how you are posting it, if you are using ajax, you can use either _GET or _POST, but if you are using submit you can put that sum into a hidden field and name it whatever you want, then you can catch it in your script via $_POST['sumoffield'];

Comment: i know this. i mean, how can i catch EACH entered value of EACH field?

Answer (score 1):

Try this server-side code:

```
<?php
    $vals = array();
    foreach($_POST as $key=>$val) {
        if(!empty($val)) {
            $vals[] = $val;
        } 
    }
?>
```

Use`$vals`. you're done.

Comment: @doniyor It iterates through the `$_POST` array, giving you both the key (index) and the corresponding value...i.e. content of the input box.

Comment: @ATaylor, i know, but in Sandy's forloop, the ``$_POST`` is alone and not like this: ``$_POST['set']``

Comment: @doniyor Which is why this will fetch you ALL entries passed to the script in question. What you do with this data is yet another question. Of course, you could always put `$_POST['set']` instead of plain `$_POST` and thereby only iterate through the input fields specified with `name = 'Set[]'`